# from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext - ImportError: No module named snappy

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snappydata, snappydb

even after reinstalling pyspark and snappydata whenever I try to import  pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext from the code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
SparkContext._ensure_initialized()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test")  \
                        .master("local[*]") \
                        .config("spark.snappydata.connection", "localhost:1527") \
                        .getOrCreate() 

snappy = SnappySession(spark)
snappy.sql("SELECT col1, min(col2) from TABLE1")
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpy.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext
ImportError: No module named snappy
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you added snappydata as a dependency as described [here](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/quickstart/getting_started_with_your_spark_distribution/) ? (assuming spark version >= 2.1.1). Also, how are you running the pyspark script? Locally using `spark-submit`?

Comment: I'm new to this. I'm just running the python script in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known problem in last released version. This has been fixed in latest master. $SNAPPY_HOME/bin/pyspark refers to the python scripts inside $SNAPPY_HOME/pyspark folder. Unfortunately, some build changes stopped copying SnappyData python scripts in the folder. You can build the current master to work with pyspark.

Comment: Check out these docs to build from source http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/install/building_from_source/